# What is the differences between Amazon Corretto and Java JDK? Why we use Amazon Corretto for specially developing Enterprise Apps?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, java-8, corretto

I work in a Bank as developer and system administrator. I have new project. The project is about identity and access management. While we develop the IAM App, we use Java Language. For this reason, I bought Udemy Java course. But, Amazon Corretto is used in the course and I didn't understand this JDK.

1. What is Amazon Corretto JDK?
2. Why we use Corretto JDK?

Comment: Oracle has changed the licensing terms by which they provide their version of the Java runtime. As Java is open-source, other vendors have provided builds based on the open-source version which do not require additional licensing from Oracle. Amazon is one such provider (as is [Microsoft](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3451297/microsoft-to-participate-in-open-source-java.html), etc).

Comment: *"What is Amazon Corretto JDK?"* That specific question is the very first question answered in the [Corretto FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/faqs/).

Comment: @Andreas - And the 2nd question in the FAQ is *"Why we use Corretto JDK"*; and the 3rd question in the FAQ is (basically) *"What is the differences between Amazon Corretto and Java JDK?"*. OP doesn't specifically mention *OpenJDK*, so people who aren't familiar with that need the info in Elliott Frisch's comment.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - Interesting. The link you provided for Microsoft is not what I was expecting, as it is basically just an announcement that Microsoft is "participating" in the OpenJDK project. To me, that doesn't necessarily imply "providing their own build". However, [this](https://www.microsoft.com/openjdk) does.

Comment: @JohnY It was an announcement 15 months ago. Now you can download it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - I know you can download it now. I included a link to Microsoft's OpenJDK build in my comment. And while there may not have been any better link available to you 15 months ago, that doesn't change my reading of the announcement. Specifically, the announcement didn't imply that Microsoft had anything comparable to Corretto 15 months ago. And even today, Microsoft does not recommend using its build in production, which is in stark contrast to Corretto.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's Amazon's OpenJDK distribution. Its no a cost  enterprise Java implementation which is supported and maintained by Amazon.

> Amazon Corretto is a production-ready distribution of OpenJDK, and it’s designed to provide everything you need to create and run Java applications without limits. Open Java Development Kit, or OpenJDK, is a popular distribution of Java used by developers to create rich applications, and Corretto is an Amazon implementation of OpenJDK. It’s compatible with Java SE, which is the standard for web applications released back in 2006.

Why use it? Amazon supported, production ready, runs on everything, at no cost, including long-term support.

If your bank is writing Java apps on AWS, then Amazon Corretto should be strongly considered.

References

1. https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/
2. https://openjdk.java.net/
3. https://www.techradar.com/news/what-is-amazon-corretto

Comment: Is amazon providing jre distribution? thanks

Comment: They do provide some JRE downloads.